# Flutter bloc state set initial value to a dynamic value from sharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I want to set the initial state to a value persistantly saved with [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). The value is the language of my app and I set the locale of my app inside of the main.dart file with `state.language`.

```
import 'storageUtils.dart';

class LanguageState {
  //TODO: set initial language to language stored with shared_preference
  LanguageState({this.language = LanguagePreference.getLanguage()});
  final String language;

  LanguageState copyWith({
    String? language,
  }) {
    return LanguageState(language: language ?? this.language);
  }
}
```

These are my `storageUtils.dart` that I use to change and get the language:

```
class LanguagePreference {
  static late SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static Future init() async =>
      _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  static Future changeLanguage(String language) async =>
      await _preferences.setString("language", language);

  static String getLanguage() => _preferences.getString("language") ?? "en";
}
```

But because the getLanguage function isn't a constant I can't initialize the state with the dynamic value of the getLanguage function. Is there another way to initialize the language state with the dynamic value of the `getLanguage` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But because the getLanguage function isn't a constant I can't initialize the state with the dynamic value of the getLanguage function.

Small correction: you cannot use the function as a default in your method call.

> Is there another way to initialize the language state with the dynamic value of the getLanguage function?

Sure. You can for example pass it in where you *create* the state:

```
LanguageBloc(String language) : super(LanguageState(language));
```

so wherever you create your bloc, you can just call your method:

```
runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<LanguageBloc>(
           create: (context) => LanguageBloc(LanguagePreference.getLanguage())
        ),
      ]
    ...
```

Assuming you have initialized your `LanguagePreference` before that.